# How to set plugin update status for custom plugins in wordpress?

Tags: plugins, wordpress

I have created a custom plugin(version 1.0) which is already installed in the site.
Now, If i have developed its next version i.e. 1.1.

So, How can I display notification like '**There is a new version of custom-plugin available. View version 1.1 details or update now.**', at plugin page in wordpress admin panel.

[image]

Would anyone please help me on this?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to upload your plugin to the https://wordpress.org/plugins/ using (SVN), You can read about
[Subversion](https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/svn/).

When you're ready to release a new version of the Plugin:

- Make sure everything is committed and the new version actually works.
- Pay attention to all WordPress versions your Plugin supports and try to test it with all of them. Don't just test the new features; also make sure you didn't accidentally break some older functionality of the Plugin.
- Change the version number in the header comment of the main PHP file to the new version number (in the trunk folder).
- Change the version number in the 'Stable tag' field of the readme.txt file (in the trunk folder).
- Add a new sub-section in the 'changelog' section of the readme.txt file, briefly describing what changed compared to the last release. This will be listed on the 'Changelog' tab of the Plugin page.
- Commit these changes.
  Create a new SVN tag as a copy of trunk, following [This Guide](https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/svn/#task-3)

Give the system a couple of minutes to work, and then check the wordpress.org Plugin page and a WordPress installation with your Plugin to see if everything updated correctly and the WordPress installation shows an update for your Plugin (the update checks might be cached, so this could take some time -- try visiting the 'available updates' page in your WordPress installation).

Comment: "First of all you have to upload your plugin..." makes some major assumptions of the asker.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is only correct if you are a major shop. You do not have to use the wordpress repos for your plugins, in fact, if you're not a major shop, DON'T as it pollutes the ecosystem with unmaintained plugins as solos move on.

I use this to ensure that my plugin dependencies are met or show a warning using the update notice.

```php
    if ( !defined('MY_MAIN_PLUGIN_IS_ACTIVE') ) {
       $file   = basename( __FILE__ );
       $folder = basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) );
       $hook = "in_plugin_update_message-$folder/$file";    
       add_action( $hook,
           function ( $plugin_data, $r ){
               echo 'Must activate Main Plugin to use this plugin';
           }, 
           10,
           2 
       );    
    
       return; 
    };
```

Comment: to be fair, i am still working on it. as i improve it i will update this answer